# How to send control commands using python's Paramiko library

Tags: ssh, command, controls, paramiko, ctrl

I need to SSH a remote machine and get onto the developer mode. To be specific, I want to execute the command **'Ctrl+gog'** upon which I will be prompted for a password. I know how to execute the normal commands, for example chan.send("enable\n"). Please provide me with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
chan.send("\x07\x0F\x07")
```

Above command worked fine for me.Just concatenate the Hexa equivalent for Ctrl-g,Ctrl-o,Ctrl-g which is, x07x0Fx07.